# linear regression fit plot over boxplots in shared y-axis

Tags: matplotlib, linear-regression, boxplot

I have a plot in the picture below:

[image]

Is it possible to add a colored band to indicate a linear regression between the different x-axis? I want a plot like this, with filling with the same color all the zone between the two green lines:

[image]

Comment: All plots have the same values on the x axis. How would you define the word "regression" in this case? I doubt that such a line would carry any meaning as its slope would be completely arbitrary and only be determined by the plotting layout.

Comment: I think adding the lines in the proposed way would show wrong data and be confusing at least. One option to show something like that could be a separate graph with one regression per sigma square while having DW-XNN on the x-Axis.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, So there is no way to do that. I will opt for the suggestion of  fabianegli. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***quick and dirty*** solution, to create a visually equal single plot, would be to use `range(1,17)` for x values and use the matplotlib functions `xticks`, `grid` and `axvline` to fine tune the plot:

```
# fake some data
xs = range(1, 17)
vals = np.asarray([0.73, 0.74, 0.73, 0.71,
                   0.75, 0.76, 0.75, 0.73,
                   0.77, 0.78, 0.77, 0.75,
                   0.79, 0.80, 0.79, 0.77])
data = np.random.rand(20, len(vals)) * 0.03  + vals
avgs = np.mean(data, axis=0)

# plot linear regr. lines and fill
xs2 = [0,20]
coef = np.polyfit(xs[0::4], avgs[0::4], 1) # values for 0.01
ys2a = np.polyval(coef, xs2)
coef = np.polyfit(xs[3::4], avgs[3::4], 1) # values for 0.5
ys2b = np.polyval(coef, xs2)
plt.fill_between(xs2, ys2a, ys2b, color='OliveDrab', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(xs2, ys2a, color='OliveDrab', lw=3)
plt.plot(xs2, ys2b, color='OliveDrab', lw=3)

# plot data and manipulate axis and grid
plt.boxplot(data, showfliers=False)
plt.xticks(xs, [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5] * 4)
plt.xlim(0.5, 16.5)
plt.grid(False)
for i in range(3):
    plt.axvline(i * 4 + 4.5, c='white')
plt.xlabel('$\sigma^{2}$')
plt.ylabel('$F_{w}(t)$')
plt.show()
```

[image]